# Choosing an option in one select box updates the rest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started building my first app in angular JS and I have hit a road block. I have been trying to create a page like shown below:

I dynamically create the controls shown in the html code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Compare Tickers</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li id="control{{$index}}" ng-repeat="oneTickerInfo in tickerInfo">
                    Ticker Info : <input ng-model="oneTickerInfo.ticker">
                    <select id="selector{{$index}}" ng-model="caches.cache">
                        <option id="options{{$index}}" ng-repeat="cacheName in caches">{{cacheName.cache}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <select ng-model="boxes.box">
                        <option ng-repeat="boxName in boxes">{{boxName.box}}</option>
                    </select>
                    [<a href ng-click="colors.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]
                </li>
                <li>
                    [<a href ng-click="colors.push({})">add</a>]
                </li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>
    <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for the controller

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('qaweb3App');

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function Hello($scope, $http) {
        $scope.tickerInfo = [
            {id:'1', cache:'adx',host:'tpa27'},
            {id:'1', cache:'asx',host:'tpa27'}
        ];

        $scope.caches = [
            {cache:'adx'},
            {cache: 'taiwan'}
        ]

        $scope.boxes = [
            {box:'tpa27'},
            {box:'tpb27'}
        ]

    });
```

I am sorry as I am not able to post the images because I dont have enough reputation to post the same.

So the problem is whenever I try to select an element from the first dropdown for caches it also populates the second dropdown.Same is the case with the other dropdown for boxes. Am i not using ng-model correctly.

Not sure whats going on. Please Help!
Thank You!

Comment: can you share through jsfiddle or plunkr? from first look it seems that the issue is in code ng-model="caches.cache" it should be like ng-model="caches.cache[0]" similarly I can identify other issue easily in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're sharing an object property for ng-model across all of your select options. Instead, you need to set a unique model for each.

Set the model to the properties of each individual item in your `ng-repeat` item `oneTickerInfo`. You should also use `ng-options` to populate the select options.

```
<select ng-model="oneTickerInfo.cache"
ng-options="cache.cache as cache.cache for cache in caches"></select>

<select ng-model="oneTickerInfo.host"
ng-options="box.box as box.box for box in boxes"></select>
```

As long as your `tickerInfo` object has properties/values for both, no default option needs to be set in the controller for the select, since the object itself will provide its own default values.

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8aAaOuXec5X8OQK8DXfG?p=preview)

[Angular docs on select (including ngOptions)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Great! If it is what helped you to solve your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ng-options?

```
<select ng-model="selectedBox" ng-options="boxObj.box for box in boxes">
</select>
```

and in your MainCtrl Hello() function:

```
$scope.selectedBox = "defaultBox";
```

Comment: This solution answers a strict interpretation of the OP's question. So, I did vote for it. But it doesn't get to the root of the issue they're facing. My answer attempts to cover that as well.

Comment: Completely agree, @MarcKline there is more to it than just ng-options.